# Using SharePoint resource files in literal

Tags: 2010, development, resource-files

I have a user control, and I would like to use there the OOTB resource files for some standard text.

So I found a resource file WSS and there a resource to view.

In code:

```
<asp:literal runat="server" id="literal1" text="<%$Resources:wss,view_selector_view;%>" />
```

But it just shows this <%$Resources:wss,view_selector_view;%> and not the resource value.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Update:
Had error which said that key could not be found: solved it by removing ";" as it was not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the Resources tag, like this:

```
<asp:literal runat="server" id="literal1" text="&lt;%$Resources:wss,view_selector_view;%&gt;" />
```

Ugly, but the only way unfortunately.

Comment: oh really, is it only for literal? or for all controls?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, Literal does what it says, so I'm not sure what, say, `asp:Label` would do if you put a resources tag in. Give it a go.

Comment: a is it possible to just call resource just as text? without any literal or any other controls? just in html: "&lt;%$Resources:wss,view_selector_view;%&gt;

Comment: and a problem now is, is that it doesnt show anything at all :(

Comment: following error: The resource object with key 'view_selector_view;' was not found.